# Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class: simplexmlelement

Tags: php, simplexml, dreamhost

When calling this function:

```
simplexml_load_string()
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function:  simplexml_load_string()
```

However, checking phpinfo I have:

```
SimpleXML
Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Revision: 299016 $
Schema support  enabled
```

What gives?!

If it helps I'm hosting on Dreamhost.

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved.

Dreamhost are using a different version of PHP on the command line than for the web site. They have PHP 4.4.9 on the command line - ancient!

This simply does not have SimpleXML built in.